# tsql - optimize case statement in select clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

This snippet in my basic select in a table is making my query from 3 seconds to 8. Any ideas?

```
case 
   when @excludeprojtag = 1 
      then qtyruletag 
      else 0 
end as qtyruletag
```

EDIT:
HERE IS WHOLE QUERY

```
select case when @excludeprojtag = 1 then qtyruletag else 0 end as qtyruletag,listid,quantity
from tb_sales where date between '1/1/2015' and '1/1/2016' 
AND CASE WHEN @excludeTestOrders = 1 THEN AccountID ELSE 123 END <> 1234
```

Comment: If you change it to just qtyruletag without any of the rest, how long does it take? Seems odd that a simple case statement is dragging it that much.

Comment: What does the execution plan say with and without the snippet?

Comment: Also, what are the potential values for @excludeprojtag? If they are just 0 and 1, then change it to @excludeprojtag * qtyruletag.

Comment: That snippet alone is not causing a 5 second difference in your query.

Comment: Show the whole query. It isn't going to be the case statement except if that is a computed column calling a scalar UDF. Except if that column is not referenced elsewhere and now including that column means an index is no longer covering - and then it isn't really the case statement but the column reference.

Comment: Could you show the execution plan for both situations. Will go a very long way to point out differences.

Comment: any answer to @DaveX's question? That might point to the covering index idea.

Comment: I don't know how much trouble the final case statement is making for you, but if it's numeric, you can do "AND @excludeTestOrders * AccountID <> 1234". That will give you a zero if you don't want to exclude test orders, which is not equal to 1234, so nothing will be excluded. But if you do want to exclude them, it will just return the AccountID since 1 * anything = anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE AdventureWorks -- 2012 version
GO       
DECLARE @includezip INT = 0

SELECT @includezip = DATEPART(ss,GETDATE()) % 2
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;

SELECT pa.AddressLine1, pa.City,
    CASE -- CASE method
        WHEN @includezip = 1
            THEN pa.PostalCode
            ELSE ''
        END AS ZipCode
FROM Person.BusinessEntity pbe
    LEFT JOIN Person.BusinessEntityAddress pbea
        ON pbe.BusinessEntityID = pbea.BusinessEntityID
    LEFT JOIN Person.Address pa
        ON pbea.AddressID = pa.AddressID

SELECT pa.AddressLine1, pa.City,
    SUBSTRING(pa.PostalCode,1,LEN(pa.PostalCode) * @includezip) AS ZipCode -- No CASE used
FROM Person.BusinessEntity pbe
    LEFT JOIN Person.BusinessEntityAddress pbea
        ON pbe.BusinessEntityID = pbea.BusinessEntityID
    LEFT JOIN Person.Address pa
        ON pbea.AddressID = pa.AddressID
GO
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;
GO
```

(20812 row(s) affected)

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 15 ms,  elapsed time = 102 ms.

(20812 row(s) affected)

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 16 ms,  elapsed time = 140 ms.

I've run this a bunch of times. Seems to me like the second one is always slower. When I first created this, I assumed that zip would be numeric, but I forgot about Canada, etc. So if for some reason you are averse to CASE statements out of general principle, you can use this method when you have a binary parameter. Here I've just set it to be more or less random.

Answer (score 0):

I think that where can be improved

```
select case when @excludeprojtag = 1 then qtyruletag else 0 end as qtyruletag
     , listid, quantity
from tb_sales 
where date between '1/1/2015' and '1/1/2016' 
  AND ( @excludeTestOrders <> 1 OR AccountID <> 1234 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the  2 where condition one on top and the other one leave it on the where clause.

```
If (CASE WHEN @excludeTestOrders = 1 THEN AccountID ELSE 123 END <> 1234)

Begin
select case when @excludeprojtag = 1 then qtyruletag else 0 end as qtyruletag,listid,quantity
from tb_sales 
where date between '1/1/2015' and '1/1/2016' 

End
```